# PSCustomObject Equality Operators

Tags: powershell

Why does the following comparison operations for `PSCustomObject` in PowerShell return `False`?

```
$obj  = [PSCustomObject]@{}
$obj1 = [PSCustomObject]@{}
$obj2 = $obj

$obj -eq $obj1 # False ?
$obj -eq $obj2 # True

$obj.Equals($obj1) # False ?
$obj.Equals($obj2) # False ?
```

Can you provide an example with two `PSCustomObject`s where `.Equals()` is `True`?

Comment: `$obj.Equals($obj2.psobject.BaseObject)` :)